# question about ?: in C#

Tags: c#

Often we use code

```
bool a; a ? "err" : a;
```

Would it be possible to write the following?

```
bool a; a ? "err"; //i want not write 'a' 2 times
```

Comment: That code doesn't compile, and isn't even close to compiling: for one, you can't mix a string with a bool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `a` is a `string` and you're checking for null, you can use the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx), `??`:

```
string a = null;
a = GetString();
string s = a ?? "error";
```

For boolean values you can use `&&` or `||`, depending on what you're trying to achieve.